# How to produce messages to selected partition using kafka-console-producer?

Tags: apache-kafka

According to the Kafka documentation:

> The producer is responsible for choosing which message to assign to which partition within the topic.

How can I send messages to a selected partition using `kafka-console-producer.sh`?

I would like to specify some sort of 'partition id' at message sending.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kafka-console-producer.sh` doesn't support producing messages to a particular partition out of the box.

However it should be pretty straightforward to update the script to pass an extra parameter for partition Id and then handle it in a custom partitioner as described in the post by @Chiron in a modified version of kafka.tools.ConsoleProducer class.

Take a look at the source code at:

https://apache.googlesource.com/kafka/+/refs/heads/trunk/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh
https://apache.googlesource.com/kafka/+/refs/heads/trunk/core/src/main/scala/kafka/tools/ConsoleProducer.scala

Answer (score 21):

Targeting a specicic partition is not possible, but the `ConsoleProducer` does support writing keyed messages to the topic.

Kafka will use the hash of the key to distribute the message into partitions, at least with the default behaviour.

Currently, the default separator is `\t`, so entering `key[\t]message` will distribute it amongst partitions:

```
key1    a-message
```

The separator can be changed by providing the `key.separator` configuration, for example:

```
kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9092,localhost:9093 \
  --topic mytopic --property key.separator=,
```

Send messages like this:

```
key2,another-message
```

I have tested this with the default tab and a custom separator successfully. The messages were distributed to two separate partitions.

Comment: It worked for me also. Value can contain separator also. It just looked for the first separator position and split record into two tokens

Comment: How to retrieve the messages in console consumer according to the partitions?

Comment: Consider using something like [kafkacat](https://github.com/edenhill/kafkacat/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: kafka-console-consumer accepts the print.key property. You can also customize the string to separate the key and value in the output: key.separator.

 --property print.key=true


 --property key.separator=" - "

Answer (score 16):

According to the current state of things (Kafka>=0.10.0.1), the kafka-console-producer.sh script and the underlying ConsoleProducer java class support sending data with a partition key but such support is disabled by default and has to be enabled from the CLI.

Note that the partition key is not necessarily the same as the "partition id". By default, the partition is calculated from the key using `kafka.producer.DefaultPartitioner`, and you would either need to change that (for that you'd need to add the new Partitioner implementation to the classpath that kafka-console-producer.sh uses), or figure out which is the partition id from the partition key, depending on your use case and what your readers expect.

In any case, to enable parsing keys for the messages you'll need to set the property `parse.key` to true (by default it's false). Also, if you want to use something different than a tab character, use `key.separator` as specified in Cedric's answer.

In the end, the command line would be:

```
kafka-console.producer.sh --broker-list kafka:9092,kafka2:9092 \
    --topic $TOPIC --property parse.key=true --property key.separator=|
```

Comment: This sends a key, sure, but that doesn't guarantee a "specific partition" as the OP wanted

Comment: Thanks, I re-edited to try to make the answer, hopefully, a bit more clear.

Answer (score 8):

Here is your starting point:
`partitioner.class` setting in your `Properties` instance. In Kafka, the default implementation is `kafka.producer.DefaultPartitioner`.

The goal of that setting is:

> The partitioner class for partitioning messages amongst sub-topics. The default partitioner is based on the hash of the key.

This means that if you want to change the behaviour of the default partitioner , such as targeting a specific partition, then you need to create your own implementation of `kafka.producer.Partitioner` interface.

I would suggest to be really careful when creating your own strategy and really, test it a lot and monitor your topics and their partitions.

When it is built as a JAR, you can set the path to the JAR in CLI `CLASSPATH` variable, then `kafka-console-producer` will be able to detect and use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
C:\arunsingh\demo\kafka_2.13-2.4.0\bin\windows>kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list 127.0.0.1:9094 --topic arun_topic --property parse.key=true --property key.separator=, --producer-property acks=all
>myKey1, Message with key
>myKey2, Message with key 2
>
```

Comment: But how do we include the key as well in the stored message (worst case I can duplicate it)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question about how to send data to a specific partition, and doesn't add to the existing answers