# Publishing specific kind of message to specific partition to a Kafka topic from Spring boot Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am working on a spring boot application, which publishes and consumes thousands of messages from Kafka every minute.

- Lets say I have 3 kinds of messages MSG-1, MSG-2, MSG-3
- One of the Kafka topic with name **kafka-topic** and has **4 Partitions**.

**Requirement**

- MSG-1 should get published only to Partition - 1
- MSG-2, MSG-3 can published to any of the partitions from Partition 2 to Partition 4. But not Partition - 1.

[image]

I already tried the following sample code as POC

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("bootstrap.servers", "your_bootstrap_servers");
        properties.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
        properties.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

        KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = new KafkaProducer<>(properties);

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>("your_topic", 1, "key", "Message for partition 1: " + i);
            producer.send(record);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>("your_topic", "key", "Message for any partition: " + i);
            producer.send(record);
        }
        producer.close();
    }
```

In the above code, required messages are going to Partition - 1 but other messages are going to Partition - 2 to Partition - 4 **including Partition 1**.

Can anyone to help with the above use case. To have message specific partitions?

> **Overall Goal**
>
> I want to process Specific kind of messages(MSG-1) whose count would
> be less than 5% compared to MSG-2, MSG-3, in a seperate partition so
> these messages(MSG-1) gets processed faster compare to other
> Messages(MSG-2, MSG-3)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send message to a particular partition in Kafka?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50324249/how-to-send-message-to-a-particular-partition-in-kafka)